# HTML Attribute CHtml::link

Tags: php, image, yii

I know there's also another post with this kind of question. But there was no (correct) answer that's why i wanted to open a new one to help me and also other people who want to know this.'

In the code below i want to add an onmouseover to have an hover effect on the image, is this possible? If yes could you help me please out?

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image($home['src'], $home['alt']), Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"));
```

It's written in Yii framework and PHP. Thanks in advance!

**THANKS EVERYONE WHO HELPED ME!**

I am very grateful to you for this, and hopefully the people who need it and are reading this too. And thanks for the quick response!

This is the working code

```
 echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image($home['src'], $home['alt'],array("onmouseover" => "this.src='/LimeSurvey/styles/scanyours/images/home1.png';")), Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add on image too

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image($home['src'], $home['alt'],array('onmouseover'=>'your function'), Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"));
```

Comment: I understand, but in 'your function' i put my img src code but it wont work.

Like this : `image($home['src'], $home['alt'],array('onmouseover'=>'/LimeSurvey/styles/scanyours/images/scanyours.png'), Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use htmloptions for this. it basically adds attributes.

```
echo CHtml::link(
        CHtml::image($home['src'], $home['alt']), 
        Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"),
        array("onmouseover" => "youronmouseovercall()")
);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail

Another option would be to use a CSS mouseover

```
#yourlement:hover
{
  color: #f00;
}
```

or use something like jquery

```
$("#yourelement").mouseover(function(){
  // do whatever you want here.
});
```

for the CSS or Jquery mouseover you can add the id with htmloptions.

```
echo CHtml::link(
            CHtml::image($home['src'], $home['alt']), 
            Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"),
            array("id" => "yourelement")
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

The function [CHtml::link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail) takes a third parameter `$htmlOptions` which you can use to specify any additional HTML attributes to your link.

You have two ways to have the `mouseover` effect.

1) Use the `onmouseover` HTML attribute in your link.

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image($home['src'], $home['alt']), 
Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"), array('onmouseover' => 'someJavascriptFunc()'));
```

2) Assign an `ID` to your link and bind jQuery's [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) to it.

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image($home['src'], $home['alt']), 
    Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl("/admin"), array('id' => 'temp'));
```

JQuery Mouseover event::

```
$('#temp').mouseover(function() {
        //Your code goes here.
    });
```